# Kubernetes control plane status: "Failure"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When i run `minikube start` then my local create a cluster

```
vd@vdubuntu:~$ minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

Next I check detail of cluster by `kubectl cluster-info`

```
vd@vdubuntu:~$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://192.168.59.100:8443
CoreDNS is running at https://192.168.59.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

The confusing thing is: when I connect to `https://192.168.59.100:8443`

[image: control plane ipaddress]

Is there an error? How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes by default needs authentication to access the api server.

This article might be helpful https://nieldw.medium.com/curling-the-kubernetes-api-server-d7675cfc398c

Comment: Thank you, your share helped me to understand more my problem.